# Adding Pages to an Access Tab Control using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to use a Tab control to display the many side of a one-to-many relationship. However, I don't know at design time the number of records on the many side and was thinking of adding the number of Pages to the Tab control at runtime. But then I remembered that trying to change the design of a form needed exclusive access to the db. Has anyone successfully done this or might there be an alternative?

The one-side of the relationship has the customer details and the many-side are the details of the bank accounts for various currencies for that customer. A customer may only have one account for all currencies or a different bank and account for each currency. I was thinking the Caption of each Page of the Tab control would show the currency if there were many accounts for the customer.

Comment: How about you add a little about your table design? Generally, a subform is the answer to this.

Comment: Some details added.

Comment: Not sure about adding tabs on the fly, but I've done stuff where I've set up x amount of tabs (subforms) and make them visible as they're required?  Is that what you're trying to do?  (I'm assuming you meant "tab controls" and not the tabbed document view)

Comment: ... or maybe you just need a single subform with a combobox that filters your values based on the currency you want to view.   (That might be cleaner)

Comment: I don't think using a tab control with tabs for each sub-table record is the best way to approach this. As geeFlo mentioned you are probably better off putting whatever you would use for tab labels into a combo box or list control and using a standard sub-form. But it really depends on how many (and how varied) sub-records you expect to have for each main record and what other functionality you have in mind.